# Android Studio and "Run"ing the App: won't show on the device

Tags: android, hardware

I have just got into Android programming by downloading Android Studio, and I have encountered a problem that despite my efforts I haven't been able to solve. My problem is about running the app on my hardware device. First of all, my phone is OnePlusOne with latest updates, and I have changed the developer options to allow Android USB debugging. There's also the latest ADB interface driver on my Windows 10 computer installed automatically, and JDK is the latest version as well. When I press "Run" in Android Studio, it shows my phone all accordingly in the Connected Devices (OnePlus A0001 Android 6.0.1, API 23). When I press okay, nothing happens, I won't see the app on my phone.

I have tried Gooling the problem, but most of the people seem to have the problem with the computer not recognizing the device - mine does that.

What I have done so far is that I have uninstalled and reinstalled the ADB driver, and also factory reseted my phone incase the problem is there.

After trying to run the app, Android Studio Event Log shows: "12.56.01 Gradle build finished with 59 error(s) in 8s 252ms"

Here is an example and a little bit of the error code:

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}

Any idea what this could mean and what I could do?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Which app are you trying to run? Is it a sample? Can you add your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 59 errors are the problem. It has to build/compile successfully before it has anything to even consider pushing to the device. You haven't provided any details about the project itself, but I would try creating a new project in android studio and running that without changing anything.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your message.

The original problem was with a brand new project, meaning that the only code that existed there was the "Hello world" code. I opened a new project, but the same thing occured again.

This is the text what I found from the end of the log, but I don't know what I should do with it:

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: This is actually Android Studio crashing internally, something related to java.. try upgrading your java jdk version to the latest.